# What is the word to express the fact that 'it will not require doing something'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

> Creating a spare disk will 'x' the need for more disk space.

What is the replacement for 'x' — I can think of 'prevent', 'negate', 'skip', but I am looking for a better word to convey that 'it will not require doing something'.

Comment: Could you please add a full sentence conveying the same idea in different words as it's not clear what you want to say.

Comment: …reduce the need for more disk space.

Comment: In your case, adding a disk will **solve** or **address** the need for more space. *Obviate* or *alleviate* are also good.

Comment: Variable has changed the question in a comment on my answer, it needs editing to reflect the changed question

Comment: will **nix** the need

Comment: will nullify or just nullifies (without 'will')

Comment: I'll just comment that the sentence itself doesn't make much sense to me; I'm not sure what "creating a spare disk" means.

Comment: If the spare disk is providing more space, then the creating  the spare disk will *meet* the need for more disk space, while it will *avoid* the need to find more space on the existing disk(s).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's the far more formal term **obviate**:

> *obviate*: remove (a need or difficulty).
>
> - *The presence of roller blinds obviated the need for curtains.*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obviate)]

But **eliminate** would be my choice, neither over- nor under-formal:

> *eliminate* [verb] [formal]
>
> To eliminate something, especially something you do not want or need,
> means to remove it completely.

[[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eliminate)]

*Creating a spare disk will eliminate the need for more disk space.*

Comment: I would use "eliminate" if only because I'd probably have to explain to anyone I was talking to what "obviate" meant. "Remove" or even "get rid of" would probably be my go-to when speaking naturally, though.

Comment: It’s a shame _obviate_ isn’t better-known. It’s a very good word that’s difficult to use. Here, for instance, it would be the far more appropriate choice _if you could rely on the audience knowing it_. But you generally cannot.

Comment: "Eliminate" isn't quite right: saying that adding a disk eliminates the need for more disk space doesn't make sense, because the need for data storage still exists (and may even continue to grow) — it's just that the need has been fulfilled. Rather, adding a disk would eliminate the current disk space *shortage*.

Comment: @200_success Could then use *alleviate*, or perhaps *ameliorate*.

Comment: Although interesting, the Q is on its way to being closed for "lacks detail/needs clarity".  Need I say more? The hackers here are saying that the Q is unclear, and the subject of the sentence does not make much sense. BTW...'obviate' was obvious...

Answer (score 15):

Creating a spare disk **obviates** the need for more disk space.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obviate)
>
> *obviate*, transitive verb
> To anticipate and prevent (something, such as a situation) or make (an action) unnecessary
> *The new medical treatment obviates the need for surgery.*

The virtue of *obviate* is that it not only does away with a possible need but anticipates the need and avoids it.

Comment: Does obviate still work if the need already exists (ie too late for anticipation/prevention) and the context is finding a solution for that need?

Comment: @mcalex I think so ... although a google search for "obviates the current need" yields only 14 hits ;-). But such use doesn't sound wrong or unusual to me. Like "installing a self-lubricating bearing would obviate the [need for] annual maintenance" or such.

Answer (score 5):

Remove

remove
verb [ T ]
UK  /rɪˈmuːv/ US  /rɪˈmuːv/
(TAKE AWAY)

B1
to take something or someone away from somewhere, or off something:

> Creating a spare disk will remove the need for more disk space

[cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remove)

Comment: Is there a better word for `remove the need`?

Comment: @variable that is completely changing the question, if that is what you want please edit your question

Answer (score 4):

**Resolve**. Oxford English Dictionary, "[resolve, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/163733)", 17.a.(a):

> *transitive*. To answer (a question); to solve (a problem of any kind); to determine, settle, or decide upon (a point or matter regarding which there is doubt or dispute).

Since the action in the subject ("creating a spare disk") **will resolve** the situation in the object ("the need for more disk space"), no other action will need to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

As someone that's been working in the industry for a very long time, "Creating a spare disk will eliminate the need for more disk space" sounds weird. It works in some circumstances, but those are quite limited.

It sounds like a user needs to make a choice between two installation procedures requiring different amounts of disk space. If so, I wouldn't use a sentence of the form you presented. I would say

> Creating a spare disk will reduce the amount of disk space needed.

If it's disk space that's already being used that would no longer be used, I would say

> Creating a spare disk will free some disk space.